# Swift computed property templates?

Tags: swift, computed-properties

Is there a way to template computed properties to avoid repeating the same code over and over?  For example, right now I have a class with a block of code that looks like this:

```
private var _state:State?
private var _maxs:State?
private var _state1s:State?
private var _state10s:State?

var state:State? {
    get {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(statephore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        let s=_state
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(statephore)
        return s
    }
    set {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(statephore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        _state=newValue
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(statephore)
        if newValue != nil {statsTest(newValue!)}
    }
}

var maxs:State? {
    get {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(maxphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        let m=_maxs
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(maxphore)
        return m
    }
    set {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(maxphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        _maxs=newValue
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(maxphore)
    }
}


var state1s:State? {
    get {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(state1sphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        let s=_state1s
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(state1sphore)
        return s
    }
    set {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(state1sphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        _state1s=newValue
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(state1sphore)
    }
}

var state10s:State? {
    get {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(state10sphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        let s=_state10s
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(state10sphore)
        return s
    }
    set {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(state10sphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        _state10s=newValue
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(state10sphore)
    }
}
```

There's an obvious pattern here, and all the repeated code just obfuscates what's happening and has led to errors as I cut/paste/edit/fail.  Is there a way I can capture this pattern, and then define my properties with something like:

```
var state=ProtectedValue(_state,statephore)
```

?

Comment: You won't need semaphores in your getters, as there's no resource contention to be prevented.

Comment: Behaviors might be coming in Swift 3 (see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0030-property-behavior-decls.md)

Comment: @AMomchilov, in this case this state is shared across asynchronous queues, so the interface needs to be protected.  Still learning if this is the best way to handle it, but the point of my question is that this idea of multiple properties sharing nearly identical access patterns looks like it would come up frequently.

Comment: @Kevin, behaviors looks like what I was shooting for.  Basically a class or somesuch with a get/set that get called on property access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for generics and `inout` variables.

```
func setProtectedValue<T>(inout destination: T, newValue: T, semaphore: SemaphoreType) {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        destination = newValue
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
}
```

at the call site:

```
var state10s:State? {
    get {
        //...
    }
    set {
        setProtectedValue(&_state10s, newValue, state10sphore)
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally put in `_state10s = ` where it didn't belong. See my updated answer. It should trigger just 1 wait per setter call

Comment: Thanks, still not quite as clean as I'd like but probably as close as I'll get until behaviors or something similar come along.

Comment: I would make a generic struct that encapsulates the semaphore and the data it protects

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the best approach for now.  When I said "not as clean as I'd like", I meant Swift isn't as clean in this as I'd like-- it wasn't a criticism of your response.  Ideally I'd like to not clutter the declaration with gets and sets, but have those encapsulated somehow.  Behaviors look like a step in that direction, but until then what you're proposing looks like the least amount of redundant code.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be alleviated, besides behaviors.